# How to use treeshaking in Quasar?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using Quasar in my VueJs project. When I use the quasar its sass or CSS files override my current design. So I just wanted to import only styles for those features that I use for example if I'm using a button in quasar so I should import the styles related to buttons only. I know this can be achieved with tree shaking but I don't know how to use that.

I used Quasar button in my main file

```
     <q-btn flat style="color: #FF0080" label="Submit" />
```

And to get the desired result i need to use one of these in app.js file

```
    import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'
```

or

```
    import 'quasar/dist/quasar.css'
```

But when i do so it overrides other styles as well in my project.

Comment: It's not tree-shaking but CSS cascade/specificity at this point.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Inspect the page and check the order the CSS files are imported + the specificity of your element. Overall, read about those 2 topics so that you can troubleshoot it efficiently. Quick test could be done with the devtools, finding out what has prio and un checking the property. It's quite visual and a bit hard to explain actually. Comes down to debugging CSS.